# How to detect wether an Object came to sleep at a specific position?

Tags: javascript, game-physics, box2dweb

I'm currently writing a small game with box2dweb and I need some direction for this: I'm throwing a Box or Ball and have to hit a specific place and trigger an event when the object that's been thrown isn't moving anymore, "fell asleep" so to say.

What's the proper way / best practice for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check it's velocity to see if it's moving anymore.  Just call GetVelocity() on the body.  I believe it returns a b2vec.